# Setting the default value based on the adjacent cell in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Print_New()
'
' Print_New Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    ActiveSheet.Range("$B$7:$G$24").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    ActiveSheet.Range("$B$7:$G$24").AutoFilter Field:=1
    ActiveSheet.Protect
    Sheets("Bill (1)").Copy Before:=Sheets(5)
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect

    Range("C8:C17,D20,E20:F20").Select
    Range("E20").Activate
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("G20").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-2]="""","""",5%)"
    Range("F8").Select
    Range("F8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-3]>0,1,"""")"
    Range("F9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-3]>0,1,"""")"
    Range("F10").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-3]>0,1,"""")"
    Range("F11").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-3]>0,1,"""")"
    Range("F12").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-3]>0,1,"""")"
    Range("F13").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-3]>0,1,"""")"
    Range("F14").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-3]>0,1,"""")"
    Range("F15").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-3]>0,1,"""")"
    Range("F16").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-3]>0,1,"""")"
    Range("F17").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-3]>0,1,"""")"
    Range("C8").Select
    ActiveSheet.Protect
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Need a proper code instead of any "IF" formula.
When I write something in any cell in the range C8:C17, the default value 1 should be equal to the same cell in the range F8:F17. Which can be changed. And when C8:C17 is empty then F8:F17 should also be empty.

Comment: Please explain what the actual question is, and also include the code you are trying, thanks.

Comment: Code included, Please see it once. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't do the constant `Select` and `ActiveCell`: you might replace:

```
Range("G20").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-2]="""","""",5%)"
```

by:

```
Range("G20").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-2]="""","""",5%)"
```

And, instead of using `RC`, you might do the following:

```
Range("G20").Formula = "=IF(Offset(-2;0)="""","""",5%)"
```

In top of this, you can use the whole range of `F8:F17`:

```
Range("F8:F17").Formula = "IF(Offset(-3;0)>0,1,"""")"
```

This is already a big decrease of obsolete code.

Comment: Your suggestion is appreciated but I do not want to use any function in Range ("F8: F17"). I need a VBA code for this.
For example, if I write something in Cell C8, the value in Cell F8 must be 1, which can be changed. Such as 2, 5, 13 or any number.
And when C8 is empty then F8 should also be empty.
or
And when C8:C17 is empty then F8:F17 should also be empty